# User authentication under certain restrictions

Tags: django, authentication, passwords

I'm using django as backend of an application and for some reason I cannot use django (or DRF) request system and I need to offer functions for using my server.

Each user has access to all functions but that function differs depending on who the user is, so I have to have some method of authentication.

First option is to pass a raw user password with every url-call,  which I don't think is safe.

The second option is to use some kind of code that the client will get after a hand shake and use that.  But I have absolutely no idea how to implement this.

Which one is better and how can I secure it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to use what is called password salting. You would want to concatenate all the password strings with a randomly generated string. You would want all the passwords to end up being the same length. This is to prevent against rainbow table attacks where an attacker uses the hash to determine the length of the password. In your case you would want to use option 2 and also learn how to implement salting into your authentication system.

Comment: Thanks, any lead where I can begin? Pref.  an example in django,  or python?

Comment: Try searching some examples on GitHub. I was just offering some advice based on things i remember learning when I was into penetration testing. I don't know anything about Django as I use Flask when coding in python. Maybe if you posted a sample of your code so far I could give you some tips.